# Device is not recognizing in xcode organizer window

Tags: iphone, xcode4

Thanks in advance
  I attached a device to my mac but it is not recognized in the xcode organizer window. It is showing in itunes.It is showing yellow light in the organizer.

Comment: I had the same issue with my iPhone 3g. When i tested with 3gs,it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device should be added to device list on provision portal. After that, open it's page in organizer with device attached and press button that says "Use for development". If you don't have that button and still can't use device for development, you're probably have wrong SDK installed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem was solved by uninstall and installing the sdk again.

Comment: I had the same issue. I fixed it by restarting my Mac; after that the device was recognized by Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys. I had a similar problem and ended up solving it by restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was opening iTunes. 
In iTunes it was asked to trust the device and then it recognised in Xcode organizer.